# openpyxl запись в файлы гиперссылок на кириллице

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

столкнулся с проблемой openpyxl, судя по всему он не дружит с кириллическими ссылками, например есть ссылка:

```
='C:\Users\USER\Desktop\test_\Тест Кириллицы\Что  то на русском\И ЕщЁ Что-То на РФ\[Ищем решение_Для-Теста.xlsx]Лист для теста-2'!$A$1
```

При попытке вставить её через openpyxl я получаю ошибку: [image]

Есть ли способ обойти эту ошибку? Ошибка именно в Кириллице с Латиницей проблем нет! Но и переименовать пути я не могу.... openpyxl 3.1.2 python 3.7

Пол дня сидел с Гиперссылками и Hyperlibs - безуспешно! Самое интересное, что ошибку не зафиксировать, она "плавает" по ссылкам в списке ссылок (в примере ссылка одна, но на самом деле ссылок очень много! Может кто столкнётся, есть кривое решение ниже: Сейчас используется переходник к файлу в каталогах полностью из латинских букв, и в принципе это рабочий вариант но нет предела совершенству и хочется обойти этот костыль!

В продолжение обсуждения выкладываю функцию:

```
def change_rows():
    data = pd.read_excel('lib.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', sheet_name='replace')
    data.sort_values(by='имя_файла', ascending=True, inplace=True)

    def search_files(paths, file_name):
        for path in paths:
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
                for file in files:
                    if file == file_name:
                        return os.path.join(root, file)
        return None

    paths = data['путь'].tolist()

    replacements = {}

    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        имя_файла = row['имя_файла']
        лист = row['лист']
        ячейки = row['ячейка'].split(',')
        новые_данные = row['Значения']

        if имя_файла not in replacements:
            replacements[имя_файла] = {} 
        for ячейка in ячейки:
            if ':' in ячейка:
                start_cell, end_cell = ячейка.split(':')
                start_row = int(re.findall(r'\d+', start_cell)[0])
                end_row = int(re.findall(r'\d+', end_cell)[0])
                start_column = column_index_from_string(re.findall(r'[A-Z]+', start_cell)[0])
                end_column = column_index_from_string(re.findall(r'[A-Z]+', end_cell)[0])

                for row in range(start_row, end_row + 1): 
                    for column in range(start_column, end_column + 1):
                        replacements[имя_файла][(лист, row, column)] = новые_данные
            else:
                cell = (
                    лист, int(re.findall(r'\d+', ячейка)[0]),
                    column_index_from_string(re.findall(r'[A-Z]+', ячейка)[0]))
                replacements[имя_файла][cell] = новые_данные

    for имя_файла, замены in replacements.items():
        target_file_path = search_files(paths, имя_файла)

        if target_file_path is not None:
            workbook = load_workbook(target_file_path)
        else:
            print(f"Файл {имя_файла} не найден в указанных путях. -> продолжаем замену данных...")
            continue

        for (лист, row, column), новые_данные in замены.items():
            sheet = workbook[лист]
            sheet.cell(row=row, column=column, value=новые_данные)
            print(f"Файл: {имя_файла}; Лист: {лист}; Новые данные: {новые_данные};")

        workbook.save(target_file_path)
        workbook.close()

    messagebox.showinfo("ОК", "Данные скопированы!")
```

так как файл lib добавить невозможно там порядка 40000 тысяч записей выкладываю скрин по данным из которой ошибка сохранянется:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проблема **не воспроизводится** на Python 3.11, openpyxl 3.1.2. Можно привести код и данные ссылок, приближенные к реальным?

Comment: @Алексей Р Добавил! не получилось выложить сам файл lib

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать библиотеку для кодирования urllib.parse, перед их вставкой в openpyxl

```
import urllib.parse

raw_link = r'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\test_\Тест Кириллицы\Что  то на русском\И ЕщЁ Что-То на РФ\[Ищем решение_Для-Теста.xlsx]Лист для теста-2'!$A$1

# Кодируем ссылку
encoded_link = urllib.parse.quote(raw_link)

# Вставляем закодированную ссылку в openpyxl
worksheet.cell(row=1, column=1, value=encoded_link)
```

Comment: Спасибо за интерес к проблеме но при использовании urllib.parse данные вставляются в не читабильном виде!